# Rellenar input con registros de una tabla en sql server mediante evento change de un dropdownlis, ek proyecto en en MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Cordial saludo, estoy empezando con MVC y no he podido encontrar la solución a este inconveniente. Deseo que al seleccionar un registro del DDL me muestre en unos input el id de ese registro y el precio y el stock(en mi caso en particular), estos datos los traigo de una BD en sql server.
Gracias por su ayuda.

Esto lo tengo en el controler

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ObtenerPrecioProductoPorIdProducto(int IdProducto)
{
    try
    {
        List<Producto> oLista = new List<Producto>();
        oLista = new CN_Producto().ObtenerPrecioProductoPorIdProducto(IdProducto);
        return Json(new { lista = oLista }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Json(new { esErrror = true, mensaje = ex.Message }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

}

//este es mi dropdownlist
<div class="mb-2">
    <label for="cboproducto" class="form-label">Producto:</label>
        <select class="form-select form-select-sm" id="cboproducto"></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Esto es lo que tengo en mi CapaDatos.

```
public List<Producto> ObtenerPrecioProductoPorIdProducto(int IdProducto)
        {
            List<Producto> lista = new List<Producto>();
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection oconexion = new SqlConnection(Conexion.cn))
                {
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    sb.AppendLine("SELECT  Precio,Stock *FROM PRODUCTO");
                
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sb.ToString(), oconexion);                
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdProducto", IdProducto);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                    oconexion.Open();

                    using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (dr.Read())
                        {
                            lista.Add(
                                new Producto()
                                {
                                    //IdProducto = Convert.ToInt32(dr["IdProducto"]),
                                    Precio = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["Precio"], new CultureInfo("es-CO")),                                                               
                                }
                                );
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            catch
            {
                lista = new List<Producto>();
            }
            return lista;
        }
```

deseo rellenar un input `id="precio"`, con el precio correspondiente al item seleccionado en el DROP DOWN LIST.

Comment: Saludos. Por el momento no me queda claro si el contenido de la modal lo formas en el servidor (y lo incrustas en la modal) o es una petición Ajax al controlador. Dependiendo como tienes tu proceso es lo que corresponderá realizar.

Comment: Hola gracias por tu respuesta, podrias hacerme el favor de explicarme que debo hacer en ambos casos?

Comment: Saludos. Es más práctico y directo coloques de que forma lo estas haciendo actualmente; así se te sugieren los cambios (que serían menos) a realizar.

Comment: He intentado cuanta forma he podido conseguir aca y no me ha resultado.  de que forma lo harias tu?

Answer (score 0):

**Saludos**

Te apoyo de la siguiente manera; partiendo que conoces lo que implica realizarlo con los aspecto que te menciono. Yo aún usando modelo MVC me apoyo en Ajax (con jQuery).
Asumo que `ObtenerPrecioProductoPorIdProducto` es lo q te reforna la lista de elemento a agregar como opciones a continuación lo básico (según tu estructura de código, por eso mi sugerencia pusieras lo que tienes para indicarte lo que se tiene que agregar y donde... ahí ordenas acorde a tu estructura de código según corresponda).
Usando [Ajax de jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) generamos la petición al Controlador; en este caso al método `ObtenerPrecioProductoPorIdProducto` pasando el parámetro `IdProducto`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/NombreDeTuControlador/ObtenerPrecioProductoPorIdProducto',
    async: true,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify({ IdProducto  : ValorDelParametro}), // "ValorDelParametro" es el identificador que pasaras.
    success: function (response) {
        // En caso de éxito llenar lista de opciones (ver más abajo que explico)
        // Con un console.log(response); verifica si es la lista o la trae en responde.data
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // En caso de error lo que tu flujo indique
    }
});
```

Cuando la petición sea exitosa lo que corresponde es limpiar el `<select>` para poner lo nuevo que se recibe. Lo siuguiente va dentro del `success` del `ajax`.

```
$("#cboproducto").empty();
$("#cboproducto").append("<option value=''>Seleccione</option>");
// Asumo que es response.data que trae la lista; verifica y cambia de ser necesario
$.each(response.data, function (key, value) {
    // como se desconoce las propiedades que tiene "Producto" que es el lis que se recibe cambia lo que les corresponda a continuación
    $("#cboproducto").append(new Option(value.Descripcion, value.Clave, false, false));
});
```

Es lo básico; la parte de Ajax puede ir dentro de una función que le pases un parametro y lo envíes... bueno esto es de tu lógica de negocio y flujo del sistema.